# move navbar to right side on media query

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm trying to move a navbar to a fixed position on the right side when the browser window reaches a certain size and have it on the top when it's less than that size. With the code below (as shown in the jsfiddle) the navbar is aligning on the left (rather than the right) side when I resize the html.

Question, how can I move the navbar to the right side of the screen on the media query. According to several questions I found on SO, it should be sufficient to use `position: fixed; top:50%; right:0;` but it's not working as intended.

(Note that if you want to test on the linked to jsfiddle, you can stretch the boundaries of the html section to trigger the media query).

Snippet and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c66addfg/):

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar ul,
.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 0%;
  }
  .navbar ul,
  .navbar li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-top-right">
    <li><button onclick="jump('header')">home</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('special')">Special</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('menu')">Menu</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('map')">Map</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('about')">About</button></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have set `right`, and rightly so. But when you inpsect you can see that the element has a `left: 0` also set.

Reset the `left` using `left: initial` in the *media query* and set some `width` to your `navbar` - see demo below:

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar ul,
.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: initial;
    width: 125px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    /*width: 0%;*/
  }
  .navbar ul,
  .navbar li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">

  <ul class="navbar-top-right">
    <li><button onclick="jump('header')">home</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('special')">Special</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('menu')">Menu</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('map')">Map</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('about')">About</button></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```