# Move side navbar to the right side in mobile screens

Tags: html, css

I have a page which has one sidebar to open different pages. It is working as desired in wide screens moving the sidebar to the right side, but when I am trying this in mobile screens, the sidebar moves to the small screen. please, I need help to make it working on the right side in wide as well as mobile screens.

Following is the HTML and CSS of my page.

I have searched on the internet but I did not get any solution. From my side, I have tried to change the direction of the page in HTML but it is not working.

```css
/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #599cff;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
  /*direction:rtl;*/
  /*font-family: times-new-roman;*/
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
  /*margin: 5px 0;*/
}

#sidebar {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  /*direction:rtl;*/
  /*height:100vh;*/
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}

#sidebar h3 {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: #F0F8FF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-size: .7em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#sidebar .list-group {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: #006666;
  /*#333;*/
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar i {
  margin-right: 6px;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 4;
  background-color: #006666;
  /*#333;*/
  color: #F0F8FF;
  /*#333;#ccc;*/
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  /*border-color: #0d8686;#2c2c2c;*/
  #F0F8FF-space: nowrap;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item:hover {
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
  color: #333;
}


/* highlight active menu */

#sidebar .list-group-item:not(.collapsed) {
  background-color: #73abab;
  /*#222;*/
  /*border-color:#99cccc;#006666;*/
}


/* closed state */

#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}


/* open state */

#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #006666;
  /*#222;*/
  color: #F0F8FF;
  /*border-color:#99cccc;*/
}

#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}


/* level 1*/

#sidebar .list-group .collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapsing .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 20px;
}


/* level 2*/

#sidebar .list-group .collapse>.collapse .list-group-item,
#sidebar .list-group .collapse>.collapsing .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}


/* level 3*/

#sidebar .list-group .collapse>.collapse>.collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #sidebar {
    min-width: 35px;
    max-width: 40px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: visible;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    transform: translateX(-45px);
    /*position: fixed;*/
  }
  #sidebar.show {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  #sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
  }
  #sidebar,
  #sidebar .list-group {
    min-width: 35px;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
  #sidebar .list-group .collapse.show,
  #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 190px;
    top: 0;
  }
  #sidebar .list-group>.list-group-item {
    text-align: center;
    padding: .75rem .5rem;
  }
  #sidebar h3 {
    font-size: .50em;
  }
  /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
  #sidebar .list-group>.list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
  #sidebar .list-group>.list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
    display: none;
  }
}

.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}

.collapsing {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  /*-moz-transition-property: height, visibility;*/
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  /*-o-transition-property:width, visibility;*/
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.language {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 41px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Conv_STC-Regular';
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
<!--changed here from ltr to rtl-->

<head>
  <!--<meta charset="utf-8">-->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/sidenavbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/tabs.css">
  <title>Bootstrap Side NavBar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid pl-4 pt-2 ml-auto">
    <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper pr-2 flex-row-reverse">
      <!--added here flex-row-reverse -->
      <div class="col-md-3 float-right col-1 pl-0 pr-2 width show collapse" id="sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
        <!--added here float-right,-->
        <!--add "collapse" in the class to hide on page load -->
        <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-right">
          <!-- changed here from text-md-left to text-md-right -->
          <div style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="images/userid.jpg" style="width:40%;border-radius:50%"></img>
            <h3>User</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="line"> </div>
          <a href="#manifest" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Manifest/Operation</span>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="manifest">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Upload Truck Pre Arrival</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Generate DO</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Check In Gate</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Check Out Gate</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#manifest">Generate Gatepass</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#billing" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Billing</span>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="billing">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#billing">Charge/Service Codes</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#billing">Vat Setup</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#billing">Generate Invoice</a>
          </div>

          <a href="#commercial" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Commercial</span>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="commercial">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Customer Details</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Contract Details</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Creating Tariffs</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar">
            <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Finance</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#admin" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Admin Tools</span>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="admin">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Modules</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Menu Items</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">User Group</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Login Users</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Bilingual Interface Setup</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">Bilingual Message Setup</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#commercial">System Codes</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#settings" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <i class="fa fa-sliders"></i>
            <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Settings</span>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse" id="settings">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#settings">Company Profile</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line"> </div>
      </div>
      <main class="col-md-12 col px-5 pl-md-2 pt-0 main mx-auto" style="background-color:white;border-radius:4px">
        <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
          <div class="col-md-1 pl-md-0">
            <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">
              <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x py-2 p-1"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 pl-md-0 pl-5">
            <div class="pt-3">
              <h6>Saudi Development & Export Services Co. Ltd.</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 pl-0 pr-5" style="text-align:left">
            <div class="language pt-1">
              <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> English
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 pl-0">
            <p class="lead">DashBoard</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="os-tabs-controls">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills upper">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#para" aria-expanded="true">Item1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#control" aria-expanded="false">Item2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div id="para" class="tab-pane active" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
              <div class="col-md-10 pl-1 pt-1" style="border-top:3px solid black">
                <button role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-expanded="true">
                        horizontal collapsible
                      </button>
                <div id="demo" class="width collapse show" aria-expanded="true">
                  <div class="list-group">
                    <!--style="width:600px;"-->
                    <p>
                      Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta
                      gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-2 pl-md-0 pl-1 pt-1" style="border-top:3px solid black">
                <button role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" aria-expanded="true">
                        vertical collapsible
                      </button>
                <div id="demo2" class="height collapse show" aria-expanded="true">
                  <div class="list-group">
                    <!--style="width:200px;"-->
                    <p>
                      Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="control" class="tab-pane" aria-expanded="false">
            <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0 pt-2" style="border-top:3px solid black">
              <div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
                <label>User ID:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 pl-md-0 pl-1">
                <input type="text" name="username" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
              <div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
                <label>User Password:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 pl-md-0 pl-1">
                <input type="password" name="password" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pl-md-1 pl-0">
              <div class="col-md-2 pl-1">
                <label>User Profile:</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 pl-md-0 pl-1">
                <input type="text" name="profile" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move navbar to right side on media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773404/move-navbar-to-right-side-on-media-query)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.navbar ul,
.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: initial;
    width: 125px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    /*width: 0%;*/
  }
  .navbar ul,
  .navbar li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">

  <ul class="navbar-top-right">
    <li><button onclick="jump('header')">home</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('special')">Special</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('menu')">Menu</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('map')">Map</button></li>
    <li><button onclick="jump('about')">About</button></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```